# Can't DSolve two-body problem using Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

EDIT:

@auxsvr is correct that I had the force equations wrong, and about the 
-3/2 exponent.

Another way to see this it to simply to 2 dimensions and consider a 
force acting from the origin, proportional to 1/r^2 just like gravity, 
where r is the distance from the origin.

At (x,y), the force acts in the direction (-x,-y). However, that's 
just the direction, not the magnitude. If we use k as the constant of 
proportionality, the force is (-kx, -ky).

The magnitude of the force is thus Sqrt[(-kx)^2+(-ky)^2], or 
k*Sqrt[x^2+y^2], or k*Sqrt[r^2] or k*r

Since the force magnitude is also 1/r^2, this gives us k= 1/r^3.

The force is thus (-x/r^3, -y/r^3).

Since I was initially using r^2 as my primary quantity, that's (r^2)^(-3/2), which is where the 3/2 comes from.

This effectively invalidates my question, although it still makes an 
interesting theoretical discussion.

I retried this Mathematica with the correct equations, but still got 
no answer. As other points out, the result is only an ellipse under 
certain conditions (could be a parabola or hyperbola in other cases).

Additionally, although the eventual orbit is a conic section, the 
initial orbit may spiral in or out until the final conic section orbit 
is achieved.

EDIT ENDS HERE

I'm using Mathematica to solve the two-body problem:

```
DSolve[{
    d2[t] == (x1[t]-x0[t])^2 + (y1[t]-y0[t])^2 + (z1[t]-z0[t])^2,
    D[x0[t], t,t] == (x1[t]-x0[t])/d2[t],
    D[y0[t], t,t] == (y1[t]-y0[t])/d2[t],
    D[z0[t], t,t] == (z1[t]-z0[t])/d2[t],
    D[x1[t], t,t] == -(x1[t]-x0[t])/d2[t],
    D[y1[t], t,t] == -(y1[t]-y0[t])/d2[t],
    D[z1[t], t,t] == -(z1[t]-z0[t])/d2[t]
    },
    {x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,x1,d2},
    t
]
```

But I get back:

> There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined.

I count 7 equations and 7 dependent variables?

In fact, the system is semi-undetermined, since I don't provide positions and velocities at time 0.

I realize my equations themselves might be wrong for the two-body problem, but I'd still like to know why Mathematica complains about this.

Comment: You have x1 listed as a variable twice and z1 not at all, hence the message. But fixing that will not suffice to get DSolve to give a result, it will only remove the error message.

Comment: Thanks! You are right in both cases. Can Mathematica solve the 2-body problem?

Comment: @barrycarter I've not managed to get DSolve to handle this. Methods include both removing the algebraic by substitution, and reducing to three equations in three variables via substitutions of the form newx[t] = x1[t] - x0[t], etc. There might be better ways, perhaps moving to a spherical coordinate system.

Comment: @Daniel, I'd even suggest reducing it even further as it is really a [2D system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem).

Comment: @rcollyer `DetectAndPostulateConservationLaws[]`could be a nice addon :)

Comment: @belisarius, it would be fascinating to attempt to write such a function. It would be probably be very evil to write, though. fascinating, but evil.

Comment: @rcollyer You want DSolve to figure out to use polar? That's just cold...

Comment: @Daniel, as I said, it would be rather evil to write. At this point, I want the OP to use polar, and let DSolve do its own thing.

Comment: @rcollyer Just in case you are not aware of http://research.microsoft.com/apps/tools/tuva/index.HTML#data=3|||

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, thinking about it, I'd like automatic symmetry detection. Of course, I don't know if it could pick up on the fact that this problem actually has [SO(4) symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Conservation_and_symmetry), but then again, most people don't.

Comment: @Null did you just circumvent the word filter with Unicode?  Devious.

Answer (score 18):

How about `NDSolve`?

```
d2[t_] = (-x0[t] + x1[t])^2 + (-y0[t] + y1[t])^2 + (-z0[t] + 
    z1[t])^2; sol = {x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1} /. 
  NDSolve[{x0''[t] == (-x0[t] + x1[t])/d2[t], 
     y0''[t] == (-y0[t] + y1[t])/d2[t], 
     z0''[t] == (-z0[t] + z1[t])/d2[t], x1''[t] == -x0''[t], 
     y1''[t] == -y0''[t], z1''[t] == -z0''[t], x0[0] == 0, y0[0] == 0,
      z0[0] == 0, x1[0] == 1, y1[0] == 0, z1[0] == 0, x0'[0] == -0.5, 
     y0'[0] == 1, z0'[0] == 0.5, x1'[0] == 0.5, y1'[0] == -1, 
     z1'[0] == -0.5}, {x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1}, {t, 0, 120}][[1]]

r = 3;
 Animate[
  Graphics3D[
   {
    PointSize -> 0.05,
    Point[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t], sol[[3]][t]}],
    Point[{sol[[4]][t], sol[[5]][t], sol[[6]][t]}],
    Red,
    Line[Table[{sol[[1]][t1], sol[[2]][t1], sol[[3]][t1]}, {t1, 0, t, 0.1}]],
    Green,
    Line[Table[{sol[[4]][t1], sol[[5]][t1], sol[[6]][t1]}, {t1, 0, t, 0.1}]]
   }, 
   PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-r, r}}
  ], {t, 0, 120}, AnimationRate -> 4
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: No dark matter, no Nobel prize

Answer (score 6):

I'm suprised no one else noticed that everyone wrote the equations of motion incorrectly, which is apparent from the plot, because bounded orbits in the gravitational potential of two bodies are always closed (Bertrand's theorem). The correct equations of motion are

```
{x0''[t] == (-x0[t] + x1[t])/d2[t]^(3/2), 
 y0''[t] == (-y0[t] + y1[t])/d2[t]^(3/2),
 x1''[t] == -x0''[t], 
 y1''[t] == -y0''[t]}
```

with

```
d2[t_]:= (x1[t]-x0[t])^2 + (y1[t]-y0[t])^2
```

since the motion is planar for central force fields. Also, one must set the initial conditions appropriately, otherwise the centre of mass moves and the orbits are no longer conical sections.

Comment: And what does it mean to "appropriately" set the initial conditions? How to understand that they are set appropriately?

Comment: Such that the centre of mass is at rest.